# How to get all type names from a database using Java Swing?

Tags: java, oracle, resultset, database-metadata, sql-types

I'd like to retrieve all trigger names from an oracle database schema.

I use getFunctions to retrieve all functions but i can't find another one for the types.

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd;
ResultSet result = dbmd.getFunctions(null, Ousername, null);
```

Here is some created types :

```
create type FINAL_obj is object (acode integer,performance Float);
create type FINAL_tab is table of FINAL_obj;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using metadata.

```
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = dbConnection.getMetaData(); 
ResultSet result = dbmd.getTables("%", Ousername, "%", new String[]{ "TYPE" });
while (result.next()) {
    result.getString("TABLE_NAME")
}
```